# PHP based Spell check control

Tags: php, textarea, spell-checking

I am developing a web site where i need to accept data from user. What i am looking at is some spell check where as and when user types it shows the suggestion. Like the box we use in while type the question in Stackoverflow.

It should be based on PHP. I am looking free opensource which i can use in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to correct the spelling of the input or provide a list of choices based on the user's input (aka auto completion)?
These are two different things.

If you **really** mean a **spellchecker**, [Ajax Spell Checker](http://www.broken-notebook.com/spell_checker/) could be what you are looking for. It uses Ajax and PHP and needs either [pspell](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pspell.php) or [aspell](http://aspell.net/).